# Update cell value by adding a string to current value with SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello dear Developers,

I am trying to add a string value to a specific cell on my SQL database but its not working somehow, I have tried with **CONTACT** but its updating all cells, even if I have added **WHERE** conditions.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$asset = "Neo";
$space = "&#160;" 

$sql="UPDATE `open_trades` SET `asset` = '$asset $space;', `laverage` = '$laverage', `live_price` = '$live_price' WHERE `id` = '$trade_id';";
```

I need `$asset` and `$space` combined, in this case `Neo&#160;` but I am not sure how to implement it, on this way its updating the cell but  its adding only `$space`, and the cell value its updating to only `$space`.

I also tried to combine values via PHP but still adding only `$space`.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: # character is making the whole variable as null. why you need to save that variable like this??

Comment: Please build your SQL using parameterised queries and prepared statements, to ensure that all variables are included into your queries safely and reliably, removing all issues with incorrectly escaped values etc.